# SAS v9.4M4 Stored process web application shows extra white space

Tags: sas, sas-stored-process

One of the customers at my client location gets extra white space on the page after the stored process web app landing page.  He gets this error on chromium edge (v85) and chrome (v87) browsers only. However I am not able to reproduce the error on any of my browsers chromium edge (v87) and chrome(v87) or even IE(v11.15). we tried to reboot the machines and clear out the browsing history but none of these tricks helped. How do I fix this error? [see attached pic showing a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My05V.jpg)

Comment: Client side, use browser developer tools to examine the console error messages.  Server side, examine the web application logs for errors as well.

Comment: Get them to disable all of their extensions so you can rule out any interference from them.